# margin notes on both sides of a single-column document

Tags: marginpar, notes

I have to write a paper for a course work. We are supposed to use a given layout with a single column text and margin notes on both sides - references on one side and section notes on the other.
I have been playing around for some time but I did not find any working solution yet.
Trying to copy the definition of `\marginpar` let to a whole lot of compile errors but that’s not exactly what I was looking for ;)

Also, having titles and graphs spanning the whole page width would be cool but I don't know if I will need it anyway. Just in case there is a class or package that can do both...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the document going to be oneside or twoside?

Comment: It should be oneside

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `memoir` package supports both marginpars and sidenotes, which can be in opposite margins.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,final,oneside]{memoir}
\isopage[6] % Quick and dirty large margins
\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
The medievalpage command generates the position and 
  \sidepar{A sidepar note}
  \marginpar{A marginpar note}
size of the typeblock according
to the principles of medieval scribes and the early 
printers, as discovered and described
by Jan Tschichold. The basic principle is that the 
spine, top, fore-edge and bottom
margins around the typeblock are in the ratio 2:3:4:6. 
Typically the spine margin was 1/9
the width of the page, which is what medievalpage 
assumes by default. This can be
changed with the optional [spine] argument. 
\end{document}
```

Note that `\sidepar` notes do not float, and so may overlap.

Sorry, as I'm a bit bogged down, this is just a quick-and-dirty answer, which I'm sure can be improved upon. I haven't, for example, detailed how you can adjust the margins to what you want (`memoir` has this built-in, so you don't need `geometry`).

Comment: cool, `\sidepar` did the job.
I must have missed it when i was checking out `memoir`...
Thx a lot!

Comment: @flo: Sorry, I also forgot to address the full-width part of the question. Check out the `adjustwidth` environment, with negative parameters. Memoir manual, section 8.5.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough thanks for the solution! How to make it work for twosides? I tried with twosides, the sidepar on the left side would overflow without wrapping to next line.