# Margin notes on both left and right?

Tags: margins, marginpar

I've been trying to put margin notes in both the left and the right margins at the same time. My attempts have gone something like:

```
Lorem{\reversemarginpar\marginpar{Left}} ipsum {\normalmarginpar\marginpar{Right}} dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
```

But here both notes appear in the right margin. I would be very grateful for ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Which class are you using? The `memoir` class has a `\sidepar` command that allows side notes, i.e. notes on the other side of the page than where the margin notes are. See [this example](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54596/margin-notes-on-both-sides-of-a-single-column-document).

Comment: Thanks very much for the hint. I'll have a look at the memoir class, but basically I am looking for a solution for the article class. I am using the article class with some (simple) modifications of my own and I am reluctant to give this up.

Comment: Thanks again. I've looked at **memoir** and `\sidebar` and the result seems to be exactly what I am looking for. However, I'm not keen on all the overhead that comes with **memoir**, nor on redoing my adjustments to the **article** class. The manual talks about a lot of work going into implementing `\sidebar` - this isn't available as a package that can be loaded into **article**?

Answer (score 24):

You cannot change the margin for side notes within the same paragraph.

Therefore you can wait until the next paragraph to do that, or use `\marginnote` (found in the `marginnote` package) instead of `\marginpar`. In this way, even the same note can write different texts depending on which margin appear:

[image: MEW]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\Right{\textcolor{red}{(Right) Lorem ipsum  dolor sit amet}}
\newcommand\Left{\textcolor{cyan}{(Left) Lorem ipsum  dolor sit amet}}


\section*{Two \texttt{marginpar} in the same paragraph} 

Lorem \reversemarginpar\marginpar{\Left}
ipsum  dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\normalmarginpar\marginpar{\Right} Ut purus elit\ldots
\vspace{2cm}


\subsection*{Two \texttt{marginpar} in separate paragraphs} 

Lorem \reversemarginpar\marginpar{\Left}
ipsum  dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\par\normalmarginpar\marginpar{\Right} Ut purus elit\ldots
\vspace{1cm}

\subsection*{Two \texttt{marginnotes} in the same paragraph} 

\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{\flushleft}

Lorem \reversemarginpar\marginnote{\Left} ipsum  dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\normalmarginpar\marginnote{\Right}
Ut purus elit\ldots
\vspace{1cm}

\subsection*{One \texttt{marginnote} with and without \texttt{reversemarginpar}} 


Lorem \reversemarginpar\marginnote[\Left]{\Rigth} ipsum  dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\normalmarginpar\marginnote[\Left]{\Right}
Ut purus elit\ldots


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

There is one limited time when you can get marginpars on both sides. If you are at the end of a paragraph in which you already placed a marginpar, you can `\par\vspace{-\parskip}`, reverse the marginpar direction and do a marginpar on the other side.

With this particular implementation, I also allow some vertical shifting to the note, with my routine

```
\mnote[vertical shift]{l/r}{text}
```

Here is the example, where you see the note on both sides of the paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*\mnote[3][0pt]{%
  \if l#2\reversemarginpar\def\pointer{\filledmedtriangleright}%
    \def\stackalignment{r}\fi%
  \if r#2\normalmarginpar\def\pointer{\filledmedtriangleleft}%
    \def\stackalignment{l}\fi%
  \marginpar{%
    \topinset{%
      \scalebox{1.5}{\textcolor{blue}{$\pointer$}}}{%
      \belowbaseline[-1.5\baselineskip-#1]{%
        \stackengine%
          {-5pt}%
          {\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{\parbox{1.8cm}%
            {\vspace{3pt}\raggedright#3}}}%
          {~\colorbox{white}{\sffamily Note}}%
          {O}%
          {l}%
          {F}%
          {F}%
          {S}%
        }%
      }{%
      3ex+#1}{%
      -2ex}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
this is a\mnote[2ex]{l}{some text for the mnote box} test%
\par\vspace{-\parskip}\mnote[1ex]{r}{both right and left}

\lipsum[3]
This is another test\mnote{r}{another mnote box test testing the
right side}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've 'edited' this answer only to some suggested edit that was fixing a typo from you, but introduced some other rubbish markup. Please revert at will ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the heads up.  Looks OK and compiles, so I am happy.

Comment: Is there any way to create a horizontal shift?

Comment: @Nadine `\setlength\marginparsep{1cm}` will change the gap between text and note to `1cm`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!