# \marginpar trick: not considered as float

Tags: floats, margins, marginpar

I've found on the net a useful trick that does exactly what the title says. This is the code:

```
\newcommand{\mymarginpar}[1]{%
\vadjust{\smash{\llap{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{#1}\kern\marginparsep}}}}
```

It works fine, the only problem is that the note is created in the left margin. Is it possible to put it in the right margin instead?

Comment: Why don't you use the package marginnote, which provides marginnotes, which are not floats?

Comment: For no particular reason: I'd like to know in which way that command could be tweaked, as I can't figure it out on my own. I find it a neat solution.

Comment: `\reversemarginpar` could be your friend.

Comment: That command doesn't seem to have any effect on my code.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123861/11604) solve your problem?

Comment: Well, it's the same as above: I would like to fix that command, without additional packages. Take it as a little challenge (as stupid as it might seem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An equivalent definition for right-side margin paragraphs would be:

```
\newcommand{\lmarginpar}[1]{%
  \vadjust{\smash{\llap{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\strut#1}\kern\marginparsep}}}}
\newcommand{\rmarginpar}[1]{%
  \vadjust{\smash{\rlap{\hspace*{\dimexpr\linewidth+\marginparsep}\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\strut#1}}}}}
```

`\lmarginpar` sets a `l`eft-over`lap` of a paragraph of width `\marginparwidth` plus a right-hand gap of `\marginparsep`. `\rmarginpar` sets a left-hand gap of `\linewidth+\marginparsep` followed by a paragraph of width `\marginparwidth`.

Comment: Very helpful and clear answer