# Tip/Advice/Question box with a symbol on the left

Tags: boxes

Some books contain boxes with additional advice, tips or questions which have a signaling symbol on the left (like a question mark, an exclamation mark, a light bulb etc.). Is there a package which offers something like this?

Comment: `tcolorbox`, with some additional efforts, as well as `mdframed`

Comment: The `\marginpar` macro, part of standard LaTeX, can be made quite flexible at placing notifications in the margin.  Here's an example of how I have used it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101553/margin-notes-on-both-left-and-right/130744#130744

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a version with the powerful `tcolorbox` and using an underlay, drawing the symbol left of the box -- I chose the `bombe` symbol from `bclogo` package, but basically anything can be placed there.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{bclogo}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}



\newtcolorbox{attentionbox}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  sharp corners,
  colframe={red},
  underlay={%
    \path[draw=none] (interior.south west) rectangle node[white]{\bcbombe} ([xshift=-10mm]interior.north west);
    },
  #1
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{attentionbox}
\blindtext
\end{attentionbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]