# marginpar on wrong side twosided first paragraph

Tags: double-sided, marginpar

I am aware there are a lot of questions about this or related but I cannot find any good general answer to any of them, so:

`\marginpar` seems to use the page number its paragraph start at to determine if it is on an `odd` or `even` page and appear on the wrong side in twosided documents if the paragraph simply runs over the `pagebreak` and the margin content does not fit the first page.

This seems to be a really big general problem. Am I missing something or is this really the case? If not what am I missing? If so, where are the (maintained packages only) alternatives?

Comment: Please, can provide an MWE, which demonstrate your problem. So far I don't remember to have such problems.

Comment: `\marginnote` is better than `\marginpar`, but please provide `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` ...

Comment: Does [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123861/11604) help?

Answer (score 1):

If it happens (and it can happen) then you can correct it by using `\reversemarginpar` just before the `\marginpar` so don't worry about it until you have finished editing then correct any that need it.